# Make the Text box disappear for the current selected record

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a checkbox in my main form which causes a text box and a button to disappear and appear when it is not checked and checked respectively. The code below works correctly:

```
Private Sub Check288_Click()
If Me.Check288.Value = True Then
MsgBox "Please Enter Reference Number and fill in the name", , "Database"
Text293.SetFocus
Me.MTM_Signature.Visible = True
Me.btn_8DGen.Visible = True
Else
Me.MTM_Signature.Visible = False
Me.btn_8DGen.Visible = False
End If
End Sub
```

My problem is this code is affecting the whole list of records instead of the current chosen record. I have an auto numbered primary key (ID) for identifying each records. Is there any way for me to make the text box and button disappear only for the current record. I am new to access VBA. Thank you.

Comment: This could not be done. You could use conditional formating on the textbox and have it formated so it blends into the background.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your reply. Is this something I can do for the current record only?

Comment: I had a go at it but I got stuck. Sorry.

Comment: Hi, I finally found the correct method. All I have to do is to copy the code into the 'On Current' event of the Form object. Any code in the form's On current property is executed whenever a new record is selected.

Answer (score 1):

In the event of Check288_Click() display a modal form and let the user enter the Reference Number. When closing the pop-up form update the database. You can use conditional formatting to hide (blend) the text box if you do not want to show it when empty.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Followed it and found a site on showing exactly the same thing with a sample database but I don't know how to assign the function to my checkbox. [link] (https://sites.google.com/site/msaccesscode/controls-2/conditionalformattingvisibility)